# C code - trying to return an integer value with system() call

Tags: c, linux, system

I'm facing an issue in my C code where my system call not triggering an if statement.  My code is trying to detect if LKSCTP is loaded or not.

When LKSCTP is not loaded into the kernel, "/sbin/lsmod | grep sctp | wc -l" will return 0.   The program should exit in this case with 2 lines of output.

If it is loaded, a non-zero number is returned, and the program should continue.

However, in both cases the number of lines from "wc -l" is being printed(?) and not correctly compared to 0, and the program is exiting.

First Attempt:

```
if ( system("/sbin/lsmod |grep sctp |wc -l") == 0 )
{
    /* no output, sctp is not loaded */
    ULCM_MSG("'/sbin/lsmod |grep sctp' failed! LKSCTP cannot be loaded.");
    ULCM_MSG("LKSCTP not installed or black-listed.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Output:

4
Sep 25 14:45:34.648 '/sbin/lsmod |grep sctp' failed! LKSCTP cannot be loaded.
Sep 25 14:45:34.648 LKSCTP not installed or black-listed.

Second Attempt (tried casting the return to an integer):

```
int check = -1;

check = system("/sbin/lsmod |grep sctp |wc -l");
if(check == 0)
{
    /* no output, sctp is not loaded */
    ULCM_MSG("'/sbin/lsmod |grep sctp' failed! LKSCTP cannot be loaded.");
    ULCM_MSG("LKSCTP not installed or black-listed.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Output:  Same as above.

I tried casting the system() return to an integer.  I need to be able to check the "lsmod|grep sctp|wc -l" value for a zero/non-zero value for pass/fail.

Comment: `popen()` is more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wc -l` always returns success (exit code 0) as long as it was able to read from the pipe and all. Try it in your shell: Both `echo -n '' | wc -l; echo $?` and `echo hello | wc -l; echo $?` will print 0 at the end. Regardless of whether there were lines to count or not. I feel like you are confusing the [exit code](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-exit-codes-in-linux) with the value printed to stdout.

However, I think you are already going too complicated a way - you can remove the `wc -l` and simply check if the exit code of *`grep`* is nonzero, because `grep` *will* give you a nonzero exit code (indicating failure) when the pattern was not found (again, check your shell: `echo foo | grep hi; echo $?` shows 1 while `echo hi | grep hi; echo $?` shows 0).

Furthermore, as user zwol pointed out in the comments, you can use the `-q` argument to `grep` to suppress the output of the line(s) that it found to stdout because you are not interested in it anyway. The exit code will still be set.

```cpp
if ( system("/sbin/lsmod | grep -q sctp") != 0 )
```

<sub>You could even get rid of the `!= 0` now but I left it in for clarity.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Cherry, I just saw this and will give it a try!

Comment: Suggest changing `grep` to `grep -q` so it doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: We did that, so now the grep output will not get printed into our process's log file.  Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

No, `/sbin/lsmod |grep sctp |wc -l` will not return 0 (or, more acurately, yes, it will, but will always do so). You mean that it will print the string "0" on standard output.
And they return exit code 0, meaning that `wc` has not failed to count the lines (it counted 0 without encountering any problem counting those 0 lines).

Likewise, if there is a module `sctp`, `/sbin/lsmod | grep sctp | wc -l` will display string "1" on standard output, but return 0, meaning that it has no problem while counting the 1 line output by `grep`.

So, what you need to do is either

- Read standard output of `/sbin/lsmod | grep sctp | wc -l`. That takes more than `system` (unless you use some ugly temporarily file solution). You'll have to `fork/pipe/exec/read` a process.
- Rely on `system` return value as you do, but do whatever it takes so that what you need to know is transmitted via exit code.

For example you could `system("/sbin/lsmod | grep scpt")`

That would return exit code 0 if there is indeed a `scpt` line in `lsmod` output. Or 1 if there isn't.

One pitfall, tho: there are other reasons to return non 0 exit code. For example `lsmod` could not exist. Or it could exist but not be runable by you. Or it could exist and fail. Etc etc.

Comment: Thanks chrslg, for explaining the true/false nature of the system() utility.  I've opted to pipe the output to a temp file, as our software is ancient and uses temp files quite frequently.  It even has its own tmp directory for such purposes.